# Save array in ng-storage AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, local-storage, ng-storage

how save and display array in angular?

example:

```
$scope.save = function () {
    var myOby= [
    { name: 'A', address: '1' },
    { name: 'B', address: '2' },
    { name: 'C', address: '3' },
    { name: 'D', address: '4' }
    ];
    //save
}
$scope.load = function() {
    //show
}
```

Any solution?

Comment: Have you tried reading the associated documentation? [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage), [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). Its well documented and explained. What don't you get? What issues are you having?

Comment: localStorage supports arrays as is, so long as they are valid JSON (that is they only contain objects, strings, and numbers - not functions). https://plnkr.co/edit/2uj19YbRreiu9Y0N9jOL?p=preview

Comment: You should read the documentations before asking such basic question. If it's something more specific, be more specific in your question then.

Comment: @cm92 Tnx men....Put answer below, I will mark your example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

localStorage supports arrays, and any other valid JSON (objects, strings, numbers), and not for example functions.

[Here is a plunkr demonstrating this](https://plnkr.co/edit/2uj19YbRreiu9Y0N9jOL?p=preview)

The angular code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngStorage']);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $localStorage) {
  $scope.text = "Hello!";
  $scope.save = function () {
    var myOby= [
    { name: 'A', address: '1' },
    { name: 'B', address: '2' },
    { name: 'C', address: '3' },
    { name: 'D', address: '4' }
    ];
    //save
    $localStorage.myKey =  myOby;
}
$scope.load = function() {
    //show
    $scope.restored_data = $localStorage.myKey;
}
});
```

As mentioned in the comments above, this information is readily available in the documentation: [Documentation](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage#read-and-write--demo)